# Error en ejecutar comandos de node js en Mac

Tags: nodejs

Estoy teniendo estos errores al querer ejecutar los comandos para crear un nuevo documento en mi carpeta de React. ya instale el Node js. pero aún asi no se ejecutan. intente instalar una versión antigua pero aun nada.

```
MacBook:React madeleine$ npm create vite@latets
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```